# Upload, rename and display the image with Ajax asyncfileupload - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

I want to upload the image to web server file and get the path and save it to database.

HTML and Javascript

```
<img id="imgDisplay" alt="" src="" style="display: none" class="img-thumbnail" />
            <ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload OnClientUploadComplete="uploadComplete" runat="server"
                ID="AsyncFileUpload1" UploaderStyle="Traditional" CompleteBackColor="White" UploadingBackColor="#CCFFFF"
                ThrobberID="imgLoader" OnUploadedComplete="FileUploadComplete" OnClientUploadStarted="uploadStarted" />
                <asp:Image ID="imgLoader" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/loader2.gif" 
                Height="21px" Width="23px" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function uploadStarted() {
            $get("imgDisplay").style.display = "none";
        }
        function uploadComplete(sender, args) {
            var imgDisplay = $get("imgDisplay");
            imgDisplay.src = "images/loader.gif";
            imgDisplay.style.cssText = "";
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function () {
                imgDisplay.style.cssText = "height:240px;width:240px";

                imgDisplay.src = img.src;
            };
            img.src = "<%=ResolveUrl(UploadFolderPath) %>" + args.get_fileName();

        }
</script>
```

C# code behind, event file upload complete

```
protected string UploadFolderPath = "~/Images/";

protected void FileUploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
             string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(AsyncFileUpload1.FileName);
             AsyncFileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(this.UploadFolderPath) + filename);
}
```

With code above, I success to do it... But the problem become when I want to rename the file with GUID, the image not appear after upload.

C# code behind

```
protected string UploadFolderPath = "~/Images/";
protected void FileUploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
    string fileext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(AsyncFileUpload1.FileName);
    string file_id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    AsyncFileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(this.UploadFolderPath) + file_id + fileext);      
}
```

I realize in the javascript, it will refer to agrs from file upload control. So that means it cannot refer the new file name.

Javascript

```
img.src = "<%=ResolveUrl(UploadFolderPath) %>" + args.get_fileName();
```

So I google to find how to paste a value from code behind to javascript. And I found it. Then modified my behind code something like this

```
protected string UploadFolderPath = "~/Images/";

protected string image = "";

protected void FileUploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
      string fileext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(AsyncFileUpload1.FileName);

      string file_id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

      AsyncFileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(this.UploadFolderPath) + file_id + fileext);

      image = this.ResolveUrl(this.UploadFolderPath) + file_id + filename;
}
```

And the javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function uploadStarted() {
            $get("imgDisplay").style.display = "none";
        }
        function uploadComplete(sender, args) {
            var imgDisplay = $get("imgDisplay");
            imgDisplay.src = "images/loader.gif";
            imgDisplay.style.cssText = "";
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function () {
                imgDisplay.style.cssText = "height:240px;width:240px";

                imgDisplay.src = img.src;
            };

            img.src = "<%=ResolveUrl(image) %>";

        }
</script>
```

Still not appear because the image variable not have a value inside it. How to solved this?

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: You have saved file with this name file_id + fileext and you are getting image variable from this file_id + filename , is it allright ?

Comment: @MairajAhmad : Exactly..

Answer (score 0):

Nothing issue with your codes, the only problem i see is that since you edited the path you must revert it back to the original values if you retrieve it unless no image will show.

Answer (score 0):

### aspx code for fileupload

```
<ajax:asyncfileupload id="Asyncfileupload1" onclientuploadcomplete="uploadComplete1"
width="350px" runat="server" uploaderstyle="Traditional" 
throbberid="Image6" onuploadedcomplete="Asyncfileupload1_UploadedComplete" />
```

### javascript function

```
function uploadComplete1() 
{
    window.location = window.location.href;
}
```

### aspx.cs code

```
protected void Asyncfileupload1_UploadedComplete(object sender, AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
    string name = Asyncfileupload1.FileName;
    string[] spi = name.Split('.');
    int len = spi.Length;
    string type = spi[len - 1];
    if (type == "apk" || type == "ipa")
    {
        if (Asyncfileupload1.PostedFile.ContentLength > 10)
        {
            string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Asyncfileupload1.FileName);
            string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);
            string newfilename = Path.GetRandomFileName();
            newfilename += ext;
            Asyncfileupload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/product_application/") + newfilename);
            MobileStoreEntities mse = new MobileStoreEntities();
            ProductMast um = new ProductMast();
            int loginid = Utility.login_id();

            um = mse.ProductMasts.Where(i => i.ProductID == proid).FirstOrDefault();
            um.ApplicationFile = "~/product_application/" + newfilename;
            int check1 = mse.SaveChanges();
            lblDoc.Text = "Old file is available. Want to change? Then Upload";
        }
        else
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "TestAlert", "alert('" + "Size problem." + "');", true);
        }
        //Response.Redirect("ProductFileUpload.aspx?proid="+HttpUtility.UrlEncode(enc));
        //Response.Redirect("ProductFileUpload.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "TestAlert", "alert('" + "Must upload doc, docx or pdf file." + "');", true);
    }
}
```